# How to access NTFS partition and erase files on clicking hard drive (part-success)

Tags: windows-7, linux, hard-drive, data-recovery, hardware-failure

Had a new laptop for 4 days and when turned on today, the hard drive (Hitachi) was clicking (hardware fault) and Windows won't load: "0xc00000e9 error - hardware fault".

Definitely not dropped the laptop or anything like that.

Loaded UBCD (USB) - Hitachi Drive Fitness Test found no drives. Then loaded PartedMagic which shows SMART errors in the drive - "Uncorrectable error in data". Can't browse the drive in the File Manager - it comes back with a read error. Can't mount the drive either. Tried ntfsfix which made no difference.

TestDisk shows the partitions and let's me browse the files! However I want to delete my personal files off the hard disk (as I'm returning the laptop) and would rather not wipe the whole partition out.

Any ideas how I can use UBCD and any other programs to let me browse and delete certain files/folders on the broken drive?

Comment: If you're getting SMART errors, the drive is toast.

Comment: @RandolphWest - Agreed. OP - Salvage what you can off it, and send it back under warranty

Comment: I know the drive has gone, I just want to DELETE some personal files off it before sending the drive back

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to a copy of [spinrite](http://grc.com), you may well find that you can recover most or all of the drive even with those faults on it.

Otherwise, I would try to delete the partition and create a new one, perhaps with a different format. Do that a couple of times to try to overwrite the whole of the disk so it cannot be recovered.